# uninitialized constant ThinkingSphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am running Rails 4.0.2 on Ruby 2.1.0, Sphinx 2.1.9 and thinking-sphinx 3.1.1
I've setup the search action in the home controller

```
def search
  @objects = ThinkingSphinx.search params[:search]
end
```

and I'm getting the

```
uninitialized constant HomeController::ThinkingSphinx
```

I have successfully indexed and started sphinx server. 
I have also restarted my rails server a couple of times.
When I try to run the search from the console it works like a charm.
Am I doing something wrong or its some kind of bug?

Comment: I want to see your model definition, and your routes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm it seems it works now! I've upgraded rails to 4.0.4 and i rebooted my vps, so the sphinx searchd daemon and my rails app were assigned with different pid. Looks like that solved it.